# Show changes from an currently executing for loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, real-time

I could need some help, or maybe just an answer. Is there a way to show changes made by aa js within an executing `for` loop ? I know there is a way with `setInterval`, but I have an example with a greater progress where I need it to progress the problem with a for loop. So here is my try:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>life change test</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8"> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var el = document.getElementById("wrapper");            
            /*var i = 0;
            var counter = setInterval(function(){
                el.innerHTML = i;
                i++;                
                if(i == 18000){
                    clearInterval(counter);
                }
            }, 10);*/
            for (var i = 400000; i >= 0; i--) {
                el.innerHTML = i;
            };
        </script>       
    </body>
</html>
```

My Firefox just freezes until it is completely done, and than displays the result. Is there a chance to actually see the progress ?

Comment: Of course it freezes, your synchronous loop is preventing the DOM from actually rendering.

Comment: JS is single threaded.  When you have a long executing script, the browser can't do anything else.  This is why we use asynchronous techniques in JS.  In the above, as a very dirty trick, you could use a settimeout (inside the for loop!) to convince yourself that when you postpone something to the next tick, the browser gets unfrozen.

Comment: One of the most expensive operations in Javascript is DOM manipulation.  For example, you can speed up your example code by calling innerHTML one time after calculation loop.

Comment: @srturkin - you are 100% correct, but it looks to me like OP is trying to display some sort of running counter - not idea of the purpose.

Comment: Kyll yeah ... ehm well it is good to know that this is supposed to happen, but how may I be able to see changes life ? @caasjj you wrote of some techniques, which would that be and I am not sure how to use this not so nice trick you mentioned arturkin yeah ... :/ well but that would not possible show the change that is made like caasjj said it should behave like a counter. Seems useless but I have an case (or just an idea) where I could need this.

Comment: @feirell you really don't have enough information in your question for anyone to give you a concrete answer.  All we know right now is you want to update some element 400,000 times with a count value as rapidly as possible.  Please fill some details and I'm sure someone can help out.

Comment: @caasjj Ok given Idea, like I generate an array and than use this array and let js generate some svg elements with this in a certain order and everything should run sequentially. So they have like an animation or something like this to establish but I don't have any certain idea I just want to play a bit with js and came across with this little issue.

Comment: Look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame